# ns-3 uniquely indexing application instances, packets and so on

Tags: c++, simulation, ns-3

I'm running a simulation with several `BulkSendApplication` instances. Is there any built-in way to select a unique index for each instance and use that when logging information (much like it does with nodes)? Also, what is the correct way to track packets and attach a unique identifier to each of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not add an internal counter to monitor application instances. Instead I used a **unique socket port** for each `BulkSendApplication` and was then able to figure out which packets belong to which node when I looked in the **pcap** file using **tcpdump**.